# Adding registry tables to db:pg:staff "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin/psql" failed to start

Tags: postgresql, sqitch

When I try to deploy my postgres database using sqitch, I face this issue
adding registry tables to db:pg:staff:

> C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin/psql" failed to start: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

But my psql in this path *C:\Program Files\pgsql\bin*. Where I should change this path, psql command added on environment variable

Answer (score 1):

this issue solved by

- added psql environment variable with your correct path
- added it in your project sqitch conf to be like that

  `[engine "pg"] client = psql`